# Update a value continuously in qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

I have an LCDNumber display panel in QT. I want to update the value of it continuously with a variable being received from an external servo motor (the speed)

I have the following code

```
HANDLE RS232Handle;
UCHAR Address = 0;
UCHAR Status = 0;
int Value = 0;
GetResult(RS232Handle, &Address, &Status, &Value);
printf("Result: Address=%d, Status=%d, Value=%d\n", Address, Status, Value);
ui->lcdNumber_TarRot_Status->display(Value);
```

All these lines must run to get the proper value. I have looked into calling a function every x seconds, and I have tried a for loop that runs forever, but nothing really works as desired. Is there a proper way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this code running in the main thread? you shouldn't be updating the GUI from a thread other than the GUI thread.

Comment: Use a secondary thread with SIGNAL / SLOTs. It will prevent the GUI from freezing and will allow information to asynchronously set the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you tried to "calling a function every x seconds" - most likely you used a blocking wait to do so. Instead, call it from a timer, without blocking the event loop.

```
class MyClass : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  Ui::MyClass ui;
  HANDLE m_device = 0;
  QBasicTimer m_queryTimer;
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event) override {
    if (event->timerId() == m_queryTimer.timerId())
      queryDevice();
  }
  void queryDevice() {
      UCHAR address = 0;
      UCHAR status = 0;
      int value = 0;
      GetResult(m_device, &address, &status, &value);
qDebug() << "Result: Address" << address << "Status" << status << "Value" << value;
      ui->lcdNumber_TarRot_Status->display(value);
    }
  }
  ...
public:
  explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {
    ui.setupUi(this);
    m_queryTimer.start(1000, this);
    ...
  }
  void openDevice() {
    ...
    m_device = ...;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a QTimer since I'm working with QT:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
  QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
  connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateMCvalues()));
  timer->start();
}
void MainWindow::updateMCvalues() {
  HANDLE RS232Handle;
  UCHAR Address = 0;
  UCHAR Status = 0;
  int Value = 0;
  GetResult(RS232Handle, &Address, &Status, &Value);
  printf("Result: Address=%d, Status=%d, Value=%d\n", Address, Status, Value);
  ui->lcdNumber_TarRot_Status->display(Value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the Qt docs on the QLCDNumber class. `display()` is a slot, not a public function. Calling it directly won't work *unless on the UI thread*. [See here for info on signals and slots if you are unfamiliar.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)

The proper usage would be to `connect` a signal of your choosing (i.e. make your own) to the ````display()``` slot.

Say you made a signal called `output_number`, once connected to the `display()` slot. You could call:

```
emit output_number(Value);
```

Which would in turn call the display slot on the Qt UI thread.

Comment: display() works just fine with displaying figures on the LCDNumber class. It is updating it continuously that is the issue.

Comment: @Scientized Understood. Could you update the question to reflect that? It was not clear that your issue didn't lie with the UI not updating.